# How to set error message through converter in wpf

Tags: wpf, validation, ivalueconverter

> NOTE: this question is 8 years old! the WPF strategy for handing custom errors has significantly changed since it was asked. please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation

I have a custom numeric text box bound to a double. 
on error, the default error message that shows (as a tooltip) is "can not convert string to double" or something similar.

How can I change that custom message?

I'm trying to do it through the converter:

```
class MyConverter : IValueConverter
  {

      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
          return 1234.23;
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
      {
           // if( value is not good)
           // ?? throw exception ?? 
      }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be able to throw your own errors within the converter, and if you have the `ValidateOnDataErrors=true` then your validation template will display the exceptions error message. I believe,I haven't done this in a while!

Comment: Definately wrong answer. See [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [validation Mechanisms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx) in wpf.Its exactly what you are looking for